# How to change the default error message in an Orbeon form?

Tags: orbeon

I can change the error (alert) message of an element in orbeon. But in some cases it is interesting to change the default message of orbeon for a form (or all forms).

As suggested [here](https://twitter.com/orbeon/status/435920399499415552). The way to do this is the use of the property:

```
<property 
    as="xs:string" 
    name="oxf.fr.resource.*.*.fr.detail.labels.alert" 
    value="This is a new fancy message"/>
```

As I want to change the english value, then must be something like:

```
<property 
    as="xs:string" 
    name="oxf.fr.resource.*.*.en.detail.labels.alert" 
    value="This is a new fancy message"/>
```

But still I only can see the original default test for the alert after restarting tomcat. I am not able to find more documentation about this, and therefore I have not idea why it is not working. Could somebody give me a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am testing this on 4.10 setup with the property you mentioned above, and that message shows as expected:

[image: Custom error message]

Note that, for performance reasons, the resources are cached. So, if you change the Form Runner resources, either by editing `apps/fr/i18n/resources.xml` or with a property, you'll need to restart Tomcat for that change to take effect.

(And if you still don't see your message even after restarting, please let us know, and we'll have to investigate this further.)

Comment: You are right, it works fine. It was my mistake. The error is that the field I am focus in, has a custom alert with exactly the same string that the default alert. This is the reason why I cannot see the changes. Removing the custom alert of the field, shows now the default alert message with the correct text.

Comment: @JorgeHortelano Ah, cool, I hadn't thought of that, and thank you for the update.